# Asp.Net core type of actionfilter to use for the scenerio

Tags: asp.net-core

The requirement is that a logged in user MUST accept privacy statement before accessing other areas of the application. I can write a Middleware or an actionfilter but not sure what's better suited.

Currently the flow will be something like below (Assuming it's a actionfilter).

1. Authenticate user and load claims from db including whether privacy statement is accepted and redirect to application dashboard.

Below things happen inside the actionfilter

2. Is user authenticated?
3. Has the user accepted the privacy statement if any available? (read claims for "PrivacyAccepted" = true)
4. If no privacy accepted claim available, redirect user to a page showing a message with buttons to accept/reject
5. If accepted, save it in database, update current user claims with a value like "PrivacyAccepted" = true (using IClaimsTransformation)?
6. If rejected, show a message and no matter what user does he'll always get the privacy statement page since action filter will redirect here until he accepts it.

From a design/best practice/performance standpoint what is the best thing to do here? Use a middleware or an ActionFilter?

Also point 5 using IClaimsTransformation should be used to update the current claims in logged in user if he accepts the privacy statement. But I haven't found any resources saying whether I can call IClaimsTransformation.TransformAsync() from my code. Everywhere it seems to be working as a middleware rather than I calling it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can define a Policy and go for Policy-Based Authorization to achieve your goal.

- First when the user accepted the privacy terms add the user a new claim. (like "IsPrivacyAccepted", true)

```cs
await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, new List<Claim>
{
   new Claim("IsPrivacyAccepted", true),
   //other claims
});
```

- Then define a policy with the required claim.

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(x =>
{
    x.AddPolicy("PrivacyAccepted", policy =>
    {
        policy.RequireClaim("IsPrivacyAccepted", true); //claim based authorization
    });
});
```

- Use the policy wherever you want to restrict users to access your actions.

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "PrivacyAccepted")]
public ActionResult Index() { //... }
```

If you do like this, you don't need to create an action filter or middleware.

---

But as I understand you also want to redirect the user to the privacy policy page if he/she is not accepted yet (does not have IsPrivacyAccepted claim). If you want to do this you can write a basic middleware as below

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
   {
      await next();
      if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
      {
         context.Request.Path = "/PrivacyPolicyPage";
         await next();
      }
   });
```

- If you don't want to define the `[Authorize(Policy = "PrivacyAccepted")]` for each of your controller, maybe you can create a base controller and inherit all of your controller from it.

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = "PrivacyAccepted")]
public class MyBaseController : Controller 
{
}
```

and inherit all your controllers from this class instead of **Controller** class

```cs
public class MyController : MyBaseController 
{
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't think about this approach. One question, how can I make this applied globally (so that I don't have to specify it in every controller?). At the moment in my code I have the FallbackPolicy set so  by default everything requires authentication. Can this PrivacyPolicy also be applied globally?

Comment: Maybe you can create a base controller class and apply the authorize on it and inherit of your controllers from it? I've updated the answer to demonstrate what I meant.